# How do I interpret this log file after starting vncserver?

Tags: linux, vnc

I am trying to configure a GCP Linux VM to run a VNC server. 
I followed the instructions here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-tZLBcfyngU and I didn't have any obvious problems.

When I run

```
$ vncserver
```

from the command line, my vnc clients fail to connect ("no response from the server") and I get this in the log file on the server:

```
Xvnc Free Edition 4.1.1 - built Feb 25 2015 23:02:21
Copyright (C) 2002-2005 RealVNC Ltd.
See http://www.realvnc.com for information on VNC.
Underlying X server release 40300000, The XFree86 Project, Inc
Wed Jul 18 11:09:40 2018
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on port 5903
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
error opening security policy file /etc/X11/xserver/SecurityPolicy
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Type1/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/Speedo/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/misc/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/100dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/, removing from list!
Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/, removing from list!
usage: xsetroot [options]
  where options are:
  -display <display>   or   -d <display>
  -fg <color>   or   -foreground <color>
  -bg <color>   or   -background <color>
  -rv   or   -reverse
  -def   or   -default
  -name <string>
  -cursor <cursor file> <mask file>
  -cursor_name <cursor-font name>
  -xcf <ARGB cursor file> <cursor size>
  -solid <color>
  -gray   or   -grey
  -bitmap <filename>
  -mod <x> <y>
  -help
  -version

**/home/nicholdw/.vnc/xstartup: 12: /home/nicholdw/.vnc/xstartup: gnome-settings-daemon: not found**

**** (gnome-panel:16661): WARNING **: 11:09:43.917: Failed to request name: the name already has an owner**
**metacity-Message: 11:09:43.976: could not find XKB extension.**

**(metacity:16663): metacity-WARNING **: 11:09:43.983: Failed to create MetaCompositorXRender: Missing composite extension required for compositing
# Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached**
nicholdw@ubuntu-with-vnc-server-and-gui-desktop:~/.vnc$
```

The config file looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solod grey
vncconfig -iconic &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
gnome-terminal &
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell script has `xsetroot -solod grey` when it should be `xsetroot -solid grey`. (I would have added this as a comment but I'm below the 50 rep threshold.

Comment: Good catch. The client still can't connect to the server and the log file has a billion more lines of output but that's another SO question. :)